# wp-nav-menu generateing an empty a tag

Tags: wordpress, menu, wp-nav-walker

Wp_nav_menu is generating my list fine  but it is adding a tags that link to home but have no content is there a way to stop these from appearing.

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
<a href="http://localhost:8888/sh"></a>
<li><a href="http://localhost:8888/sh"></a>
<a href="http://localhost:8888/sh/index.php/sample-page/"><img class="menuImg" src="http://localhost:8888/sh/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/IMG_0275-150x150.jpg" alt="Sample Page"><span class="img_text">Sample Page</span></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your functions.php

```
function page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = FALSE;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'page_menu_args' );
```

Don't forget to add this to wherever your menu is supposed to print out:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('echo'=>true));
```